# Is there a CustomStringConvertible equivalent for type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I want to implement a protocol similar to `CustomStringConvertible` for a given type but for instance.

My need is to display *type properties* values without creating an instance valuer for this purpose. Of course I can add `CustomStringConvertible` protocol to this type then create an instance value only to invoke `description`. But I wonder if there is such feature in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

## Overview:

- `type(of:)` is a function that returns the type of an instance in a `String`
- `self` can be used on the Type

## Code:

```
struct Something {
    
}

print(type(of: Something.self))
```

Comment: I want to use it on type itself not on any instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own protocol that will include a static var.

```
static var desc: String { get set }
```

on classes that conform to your protocol use it like this:

```
MyClass.desc
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I only want to know is there already such an existing protocol.